# Setting default values for BLOBs in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, blob

1)
is there any way to set default values for blobs in db2 without casting them?

I only got it working like this:
 `alter table blobs alter column testblob set default blob('20');`
2)
what would a "normal" blob look like? (i guess it's not like: '20')

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define default values for BLOB columns with [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) (Db2 LUW). There are functions like EMPTY_BLOB() to have non-NULL values and you can cast as you did. If you cast a constant, the following applies:

> If the cast-function is BLOB, the constant must be a string constant.

Later on, use [ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html) to change or drop default values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so if i understand correctly i cannot assign new default values by altering the table/ column after i have created them?

Comment: added ALTER TABLE

Comment: Thanks for your quick response